# JBoss Cluster EJB Remoting

Tags: jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I currently have a JBoss instance running with standalone-ha.xml as the config file. JBoss 7.1.1 Final. I have deployed a basic HelloBean inside a .jar called ClusterTestEJB inside an .ear called ClusterTest.

HelloBean:

```
package com.sample;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Clustered;

@Stateless
@Clustered
@Remote
public class HelloBean implements HelloBeanItf {
  int counter = 0;
  public String doSomething() {
     return "HelloBean Called"; 
  }
}
```

The HelloBeanItf is as follows:

```
package com.sample;

public interface HelloBeanItf {

   public String doSomething(); 

}
```

I got the code from a tutorial I was following.

So I have everything seemingly working. I am now trying to write a java client to invoke that EJB. Here is that code:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.sample.HelloBeanItf;

public class Client {
  public static void main(String[] args){

     Properties p = new Properties(); 
     p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"); 
     p.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
     p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
     p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
     p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://mynode:4447");

     InitialContext ctx;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext(p);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

     HelloBeanItf ejb = null;
    try {
        ejb = (HelloBeanItf) ctx.lookup("java:ClusterTest/ClusterTestEJB//HelloBean!com.sample.HelloBeanItf");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

     for (int ii=0;ii<10;ii++) {
        ejb.doSomething(); 
     }
     System.out.println("Terminated");
   }
}
```

Here is client side log output:

```
Bad level value for property: java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:30 PM org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders find
DEBUG: Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.JDKLoggerProvider
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:30 PM org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory findClientProperties
DEBUG: Looking for jboss-naming-client.properties using classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6921dcac
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:30 PM org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory getOptionMapFromProperties
DEBUG: jboss.naming.client.endpoint.create.options. has the following options {}
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:30 PM org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory getOptionMapFromProperties
DEBUG: jboss.naming.client.remote.connectionprovider.create.options. has the following options {}
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:30 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:30 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:30 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:30 PM org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread run
DEBUG: Started channel thread 'Remoting "config-based-naming-client-endpoint" read-1', selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@3a151cc3
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:30 PM org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread run
DEBUG: Started channel thread 'Remoting "config-based-naming-client-endpoint" write-1', selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@42d2821b
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:30 PM org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory getOptionMapFromProperties
DEBUG: jboss.naming.client.connect.options. has the following options {}
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientPropertiesLoader loadEJBClientProperties
DEBUG: Looking for jboss-ejb-client.properties using classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6921dcac
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector <init>
DEBUG: EJB client context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@51bc1897 will have no EJB receivers associated with it since there was no EJB client configuration available to create the receivers
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver$1 handleDone
DEBUG: Channel Channel ID 828f699b (outbound) of Remoting connection 0d818ff0 to node1-w7.wv-lab.mentorg.com/139.181.88.6:4447 opened for context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@7c572f78, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <6981170d>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=node1]} Waiting for version handshake message from server
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.VersionReceiver handleMessage
INFO: Received server version 1 and marshalling strategies [river]
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver associate
INFO: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@7c572f78, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <6981170d>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=node1]} on channel Channel ID 828f699b (outbound) of Remoting connection 0d818ff0 to node1-w7.wv-lab.mentorg.com/139.181.88.6:4447
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver modulesAvailable
DEBUG: Received module availability report for 3 modules
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver modulesAvailable
DEBUG: Registering module EJBModuleIdentifier{appName='', moduleName='ClusterWebApp', distinctName=''} availability for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@7c572f78, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <6981170d>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=node1]}
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver modulesAvailable
DEBUG: Registering module EJBModuleIdentifier{appName='ClusterTest', moduleName='ClusterTest', distinctName=''} availability for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@7c572f78, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <6981170d>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=node1]}
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver modulesAvailable
DEBUG: Registering module EJBModuleIdentifier{appName='ClusterTest', moduleName='ClusterTestEJB', distinctName=''} availability for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@7c572f78, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <6981170d>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=node1]}
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ClusterNode resolveDestination
DEBUG: Checking for a match of client address /fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:ac1e:5010%14 with client mapping ClientMapping{sourceNetworkAddress=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, sourceNetworkMaskBits=0, destinationAddress='139.181.88.6', destinationPort=4447}
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ClusterNode resolveDestination
DEBUG: Client mapping ClientMapping{sourceNetworkAddress=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, sourceNetworkMaskBits=0, destinationAddress='139.181.88.6', destinationPort=4447} matches client address /fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:ac1e:5010%14
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ClusterTopologyMessageHandler processMessage
DEBUG: Received a cluster node(s) addition message, for cluster named ejb with 1 nodes [ClusterNode{clusterName='ejb', nodeName='node1', clientMappings=[ClientMapping{sourceNetworkAddress=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, sourceNetworkMaskBits=0, destinationAddress='139.181.88.6', destinationPort=4447}], resolvedDestination=[Destination address=139.181.88.6, destination port=4447]}]
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:32 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext getEJBReceiver
DEBUG: org.jboss.ejb.client.RandomDeploymentNodeSelector@5254e73f deployment node selector selected node1 node for appname=ClusterTest,modulename=ClusterTestEJB,distinctname=
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:33 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext getEJBReceiver
DEBUG: org.jboss.ejb.client.RandomDeploymentNodeSelector@5254e73f deployment node selector selected node1 node for appname=ClusterTest,modulename=ClusterTestEJB,distinctname=
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:33 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext getEJBReceiver
DEBUG: org.jboss.ejb.client.RandomDeploymentNodeSelector@5254e73f deployment node selector selected node1 node for appname=ClusterTest,modulename=ClusterTestEJB,distinctname=
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:33 PM org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Authentication$1 run
DEBUG: Client authentication failed for mechanism DIGEST-MD5: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: Cannot perform callback to acquire realm, authentication ID or password [Caused by javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException]
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:33 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext getEJBReceiver
DEBUG: org.jboss.ejb.client.RandomDeploymentNodeSelector@5254e73f deployment node selector selected node1 node for appname=ClusterTest,modulename=ClusterTestEJB,distinctname=
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:33 PM org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection handleException
ERROR: JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:33 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionClusterNodeManager getEJBReceiver
INFO: Could not create a connection for cluster node ClusterNode{clusterName='ejb', nodeName='node1', clientMappings=[ClientMapping{sourceNetworkAddress=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, sourceNetworkMaskBits=0, destinationAddress='139.181.88.6', destinationPort=4447}], resolvedDestination=[Destination address=139.181.88.6, destination port=4447]} in cluster ejb
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:91)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionClusterNodeManager.getEJBReceiver(RemotingConnectionClusterNodeManager.java:117)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ClusterContext$EJBReceiverAssociationTask.run(ClusterContext.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:365)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:214)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72)
    at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.handleReadable(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:189)
    at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel$1.handleEvent(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:103)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioHandle.run(NioHandle.java:90)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:184)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:270)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:349)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:333)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionClusterNodeManager.getEJBReceiver(RemotingConnectionClusterNodeManager.java:115)
    ... 6 more

Apr 03, 2014 10:49:33 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext getEJBReceiver
DEBUG: org.jboss.ejb.client.RandomDeploymentNodeSelector@5254e73f deployment node selector selected node1 node for appname=ClusterTest,modulename=ClusterTestEJB,distinctname=
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:33 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext getEJBReceiver
DEBUG: org.jboss.ejb.client.RandomDeploymentNodeSelector@5254e73f deployment node selector selected node1 node for appname=ClusterTest,modulename=ClusterTestEJB,distinctname=
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:33 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext getEJBReceiver
DEBUG: org.jboss.ejb.client.RandomDeploymentNodeSelector@5254e73f deployment node selector selected node1 node for appname=ClusterTest,modulename=ClusterTestEJB,distinctname=
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:34 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext getEJBReceiver
DEBUG: org.jboss.ejb.client.RandomDeploymentNodeSelector@5254e73f deployment node selector selected node1 node for appname=ClusterTest,modulename=ClusterTestEJB,distinctname=
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:34 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext getEJBReceiver
DEBUG: org.jboss.ejb.client.RandomDeploymentNodeSelector@5254e73f deployment node selector selected node1 node for appname=ClusterTest,modulename=ClusterTestEJB,distinctname=
Apr 03, 2014 10:49:34 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext getEJBReceiver
DEBUG: org.jboss.ejb.client.RandomDeploymentNodeSelector@5254e73f deployment node selector selected node1 node for appname=ClusterTest,modulename=ClusterTestEJB,distinctname=
Terminated
```

I have tried the following:

Removing the remoting security realm, removing the username and password. I am not sure what else to try at this point.

First time poster, so let me know if more details are needed or if you have questions.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the inability to execute the EJB was fixed by upgrading from 7.1.1. to 7.1.3. After the upgrade, I was still getting the SASL exception, but the EJB was executing successfully.

The SASL exception was resolved by switching to using the ejb-client instead of the remote-naming libraries and adding clustering properties. Remote naming does not do load balancing anyway, so the switch was necessary for me.